# Not Able to See Entire Page Source of Website using Selenium,Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website
 https://script.google.com/a/macros/cprindia.org/s/AKfycbzgfCVNciFRpcpo8P7joP1wTeymj9haAQnNEkNJJ2fQ4FBXEco/exec

I am using selenium and python.I am not able to view entire page source,Basically i have to scrape the table inside it and click on next button,but the code of next and table not visible on page source.Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(link)


pass1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/div[2]/div[2]")
pass1.click()

time.sleep(30)
```

I am getting this error,NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two iframes present on the page, so you need to first switch on those iframe and then you need to click on the element.
And you can apply explicit wait on the element so that the script waits until the element is visible on the page.
You can do it like:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(link)
browser.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('sandboxFrame'))
browser.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('userHtmlFrame'))
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'charts-custom-button-collapse-left')]//div"))).click()
```

**Note: You have to add the following imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Sameer Arora,Thanks a lot for the help.You really saved my day!!!